# import org.apache.axis2.client.options cannot be resolved

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, tomcat, apache-axis

I'm trying to create a web service using Apache-Axis2 -Eclipse combo. But when i use the import org.apache.axis2.client.*; library it shows me error as cannot be resolved.

And when i went through some of the old queries here some one has mentioned that we need to add the libraries, but im not sure how to add. Can someone help me with this.

Thanks,
Thiru

Comment: Just to add additional info about my environment setup n, im using Tomcat9 version, JDk1.8, Axis2 -1.7.8

Comment: please give us the exact error message

Comment: Hi ,I have sorted it out by changing the project facet  in eclipse.